# Can a link be opened in native phone browser in webkit-based hybrid apps?

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, hybrid-mobile-app, hybrid

How can a link be opened in a native phone browser when clicked in hybrid apps ?
I built hybrid apps with Sencha Touch.

Like `<a href="www.example.com"> view me in a browser </a>`

Comment: No. At least not with anything portable.

Comment: Do you really mean another *browser* ("Here I am in Firefox and … why is Internet Explorer loading?!") or do you mean *window*?

Comment: @Quentin, I had this question, assuming he is interested in new window observing `window.createBrowser()` I have answered accordingly..

Comment: if it's another browser then ... it's a bad question..

Comment: another browser process.

Comment: @alext, why do you need to that btw? or is it just a curious q??

Comment: Do you mean another browser process for the same browser (which isn't something you tend to need these days as browsers are heading towards independent processes for different tabs anyway) or a different browser completely (in which case — why? And what do you think will happen if the browser you want isn't installed?)

Comment: "In an iOS app" is a completely different context to the implied "on the open web" that you started with… but *And for new links in the html code in the coat they can't go back* doesn't make sense. Every iOS app I've seen which embeds a browser window (Facebook, Twitter, Instapaper, etc) adds a back button to the chrome. There is no obvious reason you can't do that too.

Comment: @Quentin It is good for our project to make links go out of the app coat whatever the browser is.We haven't got a back button now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to invoke another browser?

**Yes**, there is. You can do this using `window.open()` function. But, you may read following description as why not to use it.

Please, **don't force** opening a link in a new window.

Reasons against it:

- It infringes the rule of the least astonishment.
- The back-button don't work and the user not possibly knows why.
- What happen in tabbed browsers? New tab or new window? And whichever happens, is it what you wants, if you mix tabs and windows?

The reason I always hear in favor of opening a new window is that the user will not leave the site. But be sure, I will never come back to a site that annoys me. And if the site takes away control from me, that is a big annoyance.

A way may be, that you give two links, one is normal, the other opens it in a new window. Add the second with a little symbol after the normal link. This way users of your site stay in control of which link they want to click on.

**EDIT:**

OP's question is to open a new browser and not a new window of the browser. So I am keeping this answer as it explains why we shouldn,t forcing to create new windows.

Comment: @grc I am editing it wait...

Comment: Alert!! He isn't interested in new window.. but a new program (another browser)!!

Comment: @InfantPro'Aravind Actually what i want is just to make the links go 'out' of the enveloped  native IOS enviroment.